# Why does the cube warp in unity

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I want to develop an AR application use unity and OpenCV. I use solvePNP method in openCV to get camera rotation matrix and translation as follows:

```
r11　　r12　　r13　　tx
r21　　r22　　r23　　ty
r31　　r32　　r33　　tz
```

In unity, projectionMatrix and WorldToCameraMatrix are 4x4 Matrix,which correspond to camera instrinsic matrix and camera pose

In Order to align  two coordinate system. I set
WorldToCameraMatrix=

```
r11    r12　　r13    tx
-r21  -r22   -r23    -ty
-r31　-r32   -r33    -tz
0      0      0      1
```

and I set
**projectMatrix** =

```
2*f/w   0              0                                0
0      2*f/h           0                                0
0       0    -(far+near)/(far-near))     -2*(far*near)/(far-near)
0       0              -1                               0
```

After these , the rotation and translation is correct.**But the cube warps heavily**.

As this image：
[cube warps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHgZz.jpg)

Who can help me to find the reason?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Missing open pren on the third cell third row of projectMatrix.

Comment: also projectMatrix != projectionMatrix. If this is how it is in your code you are setting a `projectMatrix` variable that never gets used.